# How can I install the drivers for Ralink RT5592 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, ralink

I am trying to install the drivers for a wireless PCIe card on my brother's Ubuntu 14.04 LTS partition (the other partition runs Windows Vista, where the card already works). We bought him this card since it advertised Linux compatibility right on the box, but so far we haven't been able to make it work.

The wireless connection does not show up in the upper-right corner, and from reading this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203226&page=2&s=d902db127c06b8689e2c51d93d88a635) it appears that we need to compile the driver ourselves. I shared my laptop's wireless connection via Ethernet with his desktop in order to download the driver source and install `build-essential`.

Unfortunately, the post seems to indicate that this works for 12.04 LTS, but it's not working for us on 14.04 LTS. When we run `make`, we seem to get errors, which I redirected to a text file and posted [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7384321/). If anybody has any ideas on what we need to do to get wireless Internet working on my brother's desktop without having to boot Vista instead, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to fix this go to **/include/os/** and open **rt_linux.h**

### Replace line *281*:

```
int             fsuid;
```

**To**:

```
kuid_t              fsuid;
```

### Replace line *282*:

```
int             fsgid;
```

**To**:

```
kgid_t              fsgid;
```