# Failling install Ralink RT5592 driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, ralink

My problem concerns the installation of a wi-fi driver (RT5592) for my new wi-fi adapter (PCE-N53) on my newly built computer. Basically, I don't manage to get the driver installed and therefore I cannot get the wifi to work.
I know I am not the only one having this issue this year, between RT5592 driver and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, in one way or the other.
Is there anybody who has ever been able to fix this problem? It does not look like on all the posts I have been through...

Following an answer to a same problem as mine (I was getting the same error message as  [Christopher Kyle Horton](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7384321/) of "incompatible types" etc), I have applied the instructions and done the editings in a script as suggested by
[Paul B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459859/how-can-i-install-the-drivers-for-ralink-rt5592-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

Unfortunately I still do get error/warnings message (a different one this time) at the end of the make and the wi-fi still does not work.
Below is a snapshot of the end of the message:

```
In file included from /home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/include/os/rt_linux.h:31:0,
                 from /home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/include/rtmp_os.h:44,
                 from /home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/include/rtmp_comm.h:69,
                 from /home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:31:
include/linux/module.h:88:32: error: ‘__mod_pci_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’
extern const struct gtype##_id __mod_##gtype##_table  \
                               ^
include/linux/module.h:146:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_GENERIC_TABLE’
MODULE_GENERIC_TABLE(type##_device,name)
^
/home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:73:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE’
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, rt2860_pci_tbl);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/username/Downloads/PCE-N53/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

[The full pastebin data is here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8088834/)

It looks from the message that one would need to edit manually some of/other scripts in the driver package, as did Paul B suggest in one case. But I have no idea how to do that.

[Here is the driver package of the wifi adapter](http://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/PCEN53/HelpDesk_Download/)

My system is as following:

```
OS: ubuntu 14.04 LTS      
wi-fi card: Asus PCE-N53   
motherboard: Asus KCMA-D8   
processor: AMD Opteron 4228 HE   
kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic
```

Following this info from chili555 in [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203226), below are some extra info about my system:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

gives

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5592 PCI2 Wireless Network Adapater [1814:5592]
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

returns

```
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If this is a kernel version (I have 3.13.0-32-generic) incompatibility issue with the driver as chilli555 suggests (the README file in the driver package says indeed it is compatible with kernel 2.6), how could one trick this around to make it work? that should be possible right? On ubuntu forums, the patches proposed dont work (leads the computer to freeze).

Basically: is there anybody out there who has ever been able to make a PCE-N53 work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (kernel 3.13)? how shall I edit the driver package to make it work for my kernel?

Comment: I think you can get it going on 12.04 using the 3.2.0-xx kernel. Please see: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203226

Comment: Can you `modinfo rt2800usb; lsusb` please?

Comment: @chilli555: I have seen your posts there (thanks they are very good!), but the only solution is still (on 20 August 2014) to downgrade the OS? there is no option for making PCE-N53/RT5592 work on Ubuntu 14.04/kernel 3.13?

Comment: @pilona: I am not sure what the list of usb devices is going to tell more? PCE-N53 is a wifi card plugged on the motherboard PCI slot, not a usb dongle.

Comment: @pilona: instead, for pci, `modinfo rt2800pci` returns [http://paste.ubuntu.com/8096789/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8096789/). Can you spot something wrong with it? If you need more info about the driver/scripts provided by Asus, see the link in the text above or here again www.asus.com/uk/Networking/PCEN53/HelpDesk_Download/.

Comment: See the PCI ID? The last part isn't even in the modaliases. Retracting answer. Should have tested first, despite not having your kernel handy. Apologies. I don't even see what I'd want in a 3.16.1 kernel, despite seeing a large number of references in the [Linux history](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/log/?q=RT5592&qt=grep).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to compile Wireless Driver for Linux Driver Asus PCE-N53 (Ralink RT5592 chipset)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699442/unable-to-compile-wireless-driver-for-linux-driver-asus-pce-n53-ralink-rt5592-c)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building the driver on your own, you can try the 2x00 driver that's part of the official kernel.

The commit history of /drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00.h in the official ubuntu kernel ([HEAD](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/linux.git;a=history;f=drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800.h;h=ebd5625d13f1832767f266f932ef012122f72e8e;hb=HEAD) also [3.13.y](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/linux.git;a=history;f=drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00.h;h=c06ffb795fcf5b174b3d50ee4ac2e11781c61a39;hb=refs/heads/linux-3.13.y)) trees show that in March 2013, some work was done to make the driver work with your chip. The PCI ID is listed, so it's worth trying.

You can also try to install a more recent kernel and see if it works, the official mainline kernel PPA has 3.14.1 for Trusty: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D

Before doing this, read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: Thx for your answer. As I'm a real newbie in linux (windows user for 20 years), I have to ask some stupid questions: Where do I get this native driver? Shouldn't my card be running, if the driver is native?

Comment: As I said, zhe driver is part of the kernel and should work right away. Perhaps you need to load the module manually, please add the output of `lsmod` to your question. Also, try `modprobe rt2x00pci` and see if the card works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my question. But `lshw -C Network` gives: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8849535/ and `lsmod` gives: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8849569/ Could you eventually have a look at it? Also `modprobe rt2x00pci` has done nothing... as far as I can see. If you need any further infos, please let me know & thx in advance.

Comment: The two pastes show that the kernel driver is already loaded but somehow does not recognize your card. Please post the output of `dmesg`, maybe there's a driver conflict, because ndiswrapper is also loaded...

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8849692/ but its huge, i that normal? shall I add a grep to it?

Comment: `dmesg` does not list the wireless card, it's not recognized on startup... Sorry, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: thank u very much for your time. I think about buying another one....

Comment: Just for completing the thread: I finally bought a card from thinkpenguin.com for 50$..... Everything is fine now.