# Need help for Asus PCE N53 driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

As the title states, I am trying to install a driver for an Asus PCE N53 (Ralink corp. RT5592 PCIe) wireless adapter on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the instruction from the link https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux

There was no error during the compilation and installation. Everything seemed to go well. But it cannot connect to any network after using modprobe to activate it. I tried the following command:

```
mmm@mmm-desktop:~/asus-pce-n53-linux$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
      description: Wireless interface
      product: RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
      vendor: Ralink corp.
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
      logical name: enp2s0
      version: 00
      serial: ac:22:0b:91:44:8e
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
      resources: irq:19 memory:df100000-df10ffff
```

It looks OK. But the following command shows an issue:

```
mmm@mmm-desktop:~/asus-pce-n53-linux$ dmesg|egrep "rt5592|firmware"
[    0.326743] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.989050] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    7.002531] rt5592sta: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.012407] rt5592sta: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

It looks the driver cannot be loaded due to the failure in module verification. Searching online, it seems the issue is related to the secure boot under UEFI. However, my Ubuntu is installed under BIOS (legacy) mode.

Any comment/assistance would be really appreciated.

```
mm@mmm-desktop:~$ dmesg|grep enp
[    1.220721] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[    7.638290] rt2860 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from ra0
[   20.708116] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   20.708123] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
```

Comment: Have you tried this older solution? https://askubuntu.com/questions/513290/failling-install-ralink-rt5592-driver-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep enp` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, the older solution doesn't work for me. Thank you anyway, darth_epoxy.

Comment: @chili555: I've added the result for the command

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up` followed by: `sudo iwlist enp2s0 scan` Does it then see networks? No need to list them.

Comment: enp2S0 is enabled after running the command: 'sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up' (checked it with the command: 'sudo lshw -C network') , and I can see a few networks with running the command: 'sudo iwlist enp2s0 scan'. But I still cannot connect to any network.